# Trying to add publishing database for Unicorn Sync when building

Tags: pipelines, unicorn, site-configuration

So I have two CD servers setup and seems like our Unicorn syncing is not completely setup because in the config it currently just has "web".
[image]

So I need to add our "web_uk" CD to this and just wanted to get your take on if this was the right way to do it or not.

[image]

Or should I switch  to <web_uk>?? What is everyones thoughts, thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to achieve here. You say you have 2 CM servers but then talk about two different WEB databases, there is no relation between these two statements.

Comment: Yeah sorry got them confused when typing this out, ONE CM and it needs deployed out to the 2 CD servers, aka web and web_uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Unicorn to publish to two different databases then yes, adding it to the list of TargetDatabases is the way to go.

As with anything Sitecore, I would not recommend modifying the configuration file directly, rather to patch the value in.

Also be mindful that a few compatibility issues snuck in on recent Sitecore releases, so you should aim to get onto at least [Unicorn 4.1.6](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/releases/tag/4.1.6) to avoid any quirks in the publishing processes.